# Scanning/Monitoring a specific process memory

Tags: c++, process-monitoring

A few days ago while playing a flash game I downloaded cheatengline just to spice up the game.

Using cheatenginge I thought to myself that it would be fun to try to make something similar myself.

So I'm wondering if anyone knows about some tutorials or articles describing how this can be done?

I've mostly found dead forums or existing libraries.

Answer (score 0):

The [original page](http://www.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot) is down right now (hopefully not forever!), but Google has a [cache](http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache%3aaNwL8l3VCBUJ%3awww.codingthewheel.com/archives/how-i-built-a-working-poker-bot%20how%20to%20make%20a%20poker%20bot) of "How I Built a Working Poker Bot".  This is a good read, which includes information on how to monitor and manipulate other processes (primarily on Windows).